# Is there an example of when I don't need to handle unsubscribing in the component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material2

I've become accustomed to unsubscribing to subscriptions I initialize in my components. The recommended approach is to use the `takeUntil` operator like so:

```
killSubscriptions: new Subject<any> = new Subject();

ngOnInit(){
   observableThing().pipe(takeUntil(this.killSubscriptions)).subscribe()
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.killSubscriptions.next();
  this.killSubscriptions.complete();
}
```

But then I was implementing a custom dialog with the overlay & portal service the other day, and I came across [this block of code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/31f0e6d5adce6005f0bf0d395798409b8c6177c8/src/lib/dialog/dialog.ts#L250) in the middle of a method in the [Angular Material Library](https://github.com/angular/material2/).

```
// When the dialog backdrop is clicked, we want to close it.
if (config.hasBackdrop) {
  overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {
    if (!dialogRef.disableClose) {
      dialogRef.close();
    }
  });
}
```

How is this subscription cleaned up? My only guess is when the `overlayRef` is disposed, the subscription is cleaned up. But how?

Are there other times we don't need to handle unsubscription?

Comment: @Stavm Fair point, but I rarely ever subscribe to an httpclient request to start out with because I use ngrx effects to handle the subscription/unsubscription. If I do though, then I normally use the `async` pipe or the method to above to unsubscribe to any httpclient requests.

Comment: Maybe stream is closed upon dispose.

Comment: @Antoniossss, indeed, from overlay-ref.ts,  dispose(): void {
...
 this._backdropClick.complete();...

Comment: Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

Because they complete the observer when the OverlayRef is considered going into dispose state.

```
this._backdropClick.complete();
```

[Angular Material CDK source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6c3442a2482e6baa0259e73deb9d1893eab09438/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.ts#L228)

**Hope this helps!** Going through the source code and trying to understand it is a good and fun way to learn :)

Edit: If you are not sure that your observer will complete then you need to make sure you actively unsubscribe to avoid memory leakage. Your takeUntil pattern is one way to go. You can even change the type from `any` to `void` on your Subject.

Comment: You're right! Should have looked closer at the dispose method. Thanks.

Comment: Asking those kind of questions is the right way to go. There might be a few places in the Material source code where all subscriptions necessarily aren't properly handled, so not taking things for granted is good sense.